# Issue querying on index

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I am getting the following log message when querying against RavenDb on ravenhq.com:

```
Issuing query on index Temp/Users/ByName for: Name:raz0rf1sh
```

Here is the code for the method I am trying to execute:

```
public User GetByName(string name)
{
    using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        var user = session.Query<User>()
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);

        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Oh snap! User does not exist.");

        return user;
    }
}
```

I can see the index, and even when I query that from the raven GUI, not results are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine, and the log message is just informational - not an error.  Is there a `User` document with a `Name` called `raz0rf1sh` actually stored in the database?

If so, then you are probably dealing with a stale index issue.  Either the document was *just* written and hasn't had time to be indexed, or this is the very first call to this  query, so it is building you a dynamic index on the fly.

You should review [the documentation on stale indexes](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/stale-indexes).

If this is a unit test, you might want to simply change your query to:

```
var user = session.Query<User>()
        .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
        .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
```

If this is production code, then you might want to consider creating a [static index](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes) for this query.